# Подключение к базе данных Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, mysql

Как подключится к локальной базе данных MySQL в Delphi 7 ? 
можно пожалуйста более расширенный ответ т.к новичок, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Много компонентов, платных, бесплатных(ADO,Zeos,AnyDAC,MyDAC,и т.д.). Напишу, с чем мне приходилось работать на практике.

**1) Через компоненты ADO( AdoQuery, AdoConnection, etc ).**

```
Находятся они на вкладках ADO кажется, точно не помню (dbGO - 2010).
Полный комплекс набора для работы mysql (и не только). Правда, для подключения нужно сперва установить MySQLODBC драйвер (скачать можно с mysql.com). 
Потом через интерфейс "Администрирование Источники Данных" добавляете источники и по имени этих источников и подключаетесь к БД.
```

Плюсы:

- правильно работает/обрабатывает кодировки
- поддерживает хранимые процедуры(компонент AdoStoredProc)
- не требует инсталляций

Минусы:

- не умеет подключаться "нативно" , то есть не работает без драйверов MysqlODBC. Ощущается в плане переносимости.

**2) Компоненты Zeos**

```
Многофункциональный пакет инструментов, также поддерживает подключения ко многим популярным СУБД (mysql,oracle,mssql,etc)
```

Плюсы:

- много возможностей, но я бы главным плюсом бы отметил - не требует драйвера, работает напрямую с БД (забиваете просто хост,юзер,пасворд. и так далее).
- бесплатное решение

Минусы:

- часто имеется проблема с кодировкой
- нет поддержки процедуры
- лишняя инсталляция(проблема с совместимостью с версией, и .тд)

Comment: Запоздало конечно, но вариант 3: компоненты dbExpress